# Why does SVM considered as discriminative model?

Tags: svm, generative-models

I read in several places that SVM is a discriminative model, but SVM has no statistical aspects per se, by that I mean that is does not estimate any probablity, specifically the postirior distribution as a discriminative model should do.

Shouldn't SVM be considered as nirther disciminative nor genreative, rather it finds a disciminative hyperplane in the feature space.

Comment: Not all discriminative models estimate the posterior distribution, some just estimate decision boundaries between classes, like SVM and decision trees. Discriminative models just enable "discriminating" between classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support Vector Machines are discriminative because they [fit a hyperplane which separates two classes](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/svm-explained). So it learns a decision boundary which is the definition of discriminative methods.

Comment: Well, according to Bishop's PRML (p 43 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf ) "Approaches that model the posterior probabilities directly are called discriminative models.", this is why I am confused

Comment: According to Jebara, Tony (2004). Machine Learning: Discriminative and Generative: Even if a classification does not use any probability it is still discriminative. But still: Franc et al. (https://icml.cc/Conferences/2011/papers/386_icmlpaper.pdf) can show that SVM are a Probabilistic Model with conditional probabilities which meets your definition of Bishop and the general one as well.